# How to store an image in configurable location in Universal Windows App

Tags: uwp

I am developing Universal windows app that requires to take photos and store this photo at a configurable location.I am storing this storage location information in a file.I read this information and I am trying to store the photo taken to this location.But the only options available to me is the App Storage Folders and the folders like Pictures.Is there a way to define a path like "D:\Photos\" and store it there without using a FilePicker or without any user interaction?

Comment: UWP apps can only access certain file system locations by default. It can't access any path without any user interaction. For more info, please see [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions+).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jay!!!